# Assign table headers as keys in Python dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I currently have Selenium populating a list in Python, with all table row values.

I want to now, put a break at the end of each line of data, and use the table headers as keys. I'm not sure how to best represent the table data in the dictionary. But my only requirement is that I can query it by table and row headers (row header being the first value in each row).

For table...

```
<table class="confluenceTable tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr class="sortableHeader">
            <th data-column="0" class="confluenceTh sortableHeader tablesorter-headerSortDown">
                <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">First Name</div>
            </th>
            <th data-column="1" colspan="1" class="confluenceTh sortableHeader">
                <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Last Name</div>
            </th>
            <th data-column="2" class="confluenceTh sortableHeader">
                <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Function</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">John</td>
            <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><span>Jane</span></td>
            <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><span>Doe</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I included the colspan, classes etc in my simplified table in case they are useful.

```
def get_test_data(driver):
    table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table")
    rawdata = []
    for td in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('td'):
        rawdata.append(td.text)
    pprint(rawdata)
```

With the above python I can get

```
[u'John',
 u'Smith',
 u'Jane',
 u'Doe']
```

I want to get

```
  {
  "First Name": "John",
  "LastName": "Smith"
  },
  {
  "First Name": "Jane",
  "Last Name": "Doe"
  }
```

Or something of the sort, so I can query the dictionary for data.

Comment: Question has been up voted ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your `html` snippet I came up with:

Part of **assign_headers.py**

```
first_names  = map(lambda el: el.text, browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr/td[1]'))
second_names = map(lambda el: el.text, browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr/td[2]'))
headers      = map(lambda el: el.text, browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//th/div'))

print [{headers[0]: first_names[i], headers[1]: second_names[i]} for i in range(len(first_names))]
```

In action:

```
In [1]: run assign_headers.py
[{u'Last Name': u'Smith', u'First Name': u'John'}, {u'Last Name': u'Doe', u'First Name': u'Jane'}]
```

Comment: Thanks @drets this has me very close. I wonder if you can help, there is a second table on my page that has td data being swept up in to the dictionary. How do I only look at the first table without giving it a class or id?

Comment: Try to add `table[1]` or `table[2]` (depends on which table you want to select) to xpath selector (e.g. `//table[1]//tr/td[1]`).

Comment: I copied your "example" html snippet 2 times (so 2 tables in the page) and I was able to select data only from first table using `table[1]/` prefix in xpath selectors as I mentioned above.

Comment: Unfortunately not for me. I have another question if you have time though. My table is simplified, and in reality I'm looking at `//table[1]//tr/td[9]` and `//table[1]//tr/td[10]`. How can I match the headings with these values? `//table[1]//th/[9]'` doesn't work.

Comment: No, I don't have time for additional questions in comments, sorry!

Comment: I figured it out `print [{headers[8]: first_names[i], headers[9]: second_names[i]} for i in range(len(first_names))]`

Answer (score -1):

this should work - its not tested but it should be close:

```
rawdata = []
headdata = []
for tr in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr'):
    tmp = {}
    for th in tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('th'):
        headdata.append(append(th.text)

    ii = 0
    for td in tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td'):
        tmp[headdata[ii]] = td.text
        ii += 1        

    rawdata.append(tmp)
```

you could probably get the headers by path from thead and the tr rows from just tbody

Comment: It's not working, I'm getting an unused variable `th` and syntax error on `ii`